# How to lock iterations in TFS 2012?

Tags: c#, tfs, scrum

As soon as an iteration (Sprint) is over, we need to lock it so that nobody is able to check-in into that iteration anymore (unless they override the check-in warnings of course).

How can I achieve this? I took a look at the Team Foundation Server SDK namespace (Microsoft.TeamFoundation) but found nothing so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I kept:

http://intellitect.com/transitioning-between-sprintsiterations-with-tfs/

In short, you use Iteration Paths to determine the current sprint.

Then you create a query that returns all work items under the current iteration (which identifies your current sprint).

You use a Work Item Query Policy to ensure that all work items associated with the check-in are part of the result of the query (and thus part of the current iteration/sprint).

Answer (score 0):

An interation (Sprint) is usually used as Iteration Path in Work Items. But from the context of your question I suggest you have a folder in Source Control for each iteration, right?

- Right click on the folder and "Advanced-> Security ..."
- WebAccess open
- Remove "Check Out" and "Check In" for all groups

Now none of your developers is allowed to check in anything in that folder and subfolders too.

Comment: We don't have a folder for each Sprint/iteration in source control. I think most people only use these for work item management.

Comment: So you want to prohibit users to associate work items of an old iteration in a changeset? Because you don't check in into an iteration, you check in into folders or you associate check ins with work items with an iteration path.

Comment: "So you want to prohibit users to associate work items of an old iteration in a changeset?" Exactly. This is the best solution I found so far : http://intellitect.com/transitioning-between-sprintsiterations-with-tfs/

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible to prohibit it. But what you can do is to force the developers to associate a work item from actual iteration. You can reach this by using the "Work Item Query Policy" (part of TFSPowerTools). You can define a query and the developers can only associate results of that query to the changeset. You have to keep the query up to date regarding the iteration, but it works.

Comment: In the article I linked, the author actually explains how to use the Work Item Query Policy without having to keep the queries up to date each time the current iteration changes.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't recognized the link. But doing it that way, you need to move the iteration, what will update all work items in it. No matter which way you choose, you need to "update" the current sprint somewhere. You just need to decide if it is in the query or in the iteration management.

Comment: Yeah I totally agree. I just hope Microsoft will release a token to determine the current iteration. http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2293180-creating-queries-token-for-current-iteration

Answer (score 0):

This is a high level idea...

Create a Global List that you use to indicate a project and its "Current Iteration".  (TFS has no concept of "Current Iteration" so you have to store it off somewhere.)  After every iteration, you will have to update this list to remove the old iteration and add then new one.

Then you create a custom check-in policy that requires a Work Item Association for the check-in.

If it does have a work item association then then you check all of them (you can associate more than one) to make sure that the iteration matches the "Current Iteration" stored in the global list.

From my understanding of the TFS Client API all of these data points should be available.  (The only one I am not 100% sure on is getting the associated Work Items in the check-in policy.  But I would be very surprised if it is not there.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using the Work Item Association Policy found in the TFS Plugin Suite.

https://tfspluginsuite.codeplex.com/